# Как посмотреть топ других стран на Google play?

Tags: android, google-play

Собственно вопрос в заголовке.Интересны приложения,которые в топе в разных странах. Подскажите пожалуйста,как посмотреть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запустить Play Store через прокси, например TunnelBear.

Comment: Он разве не из аккаунта страну возьмёт?